# What are the continuous functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_l$?

Tags: general-topology, sorgenfrey-line

Consider $\mathbb{R}_l$ be the lower limit topology which consists basis element of the form $[a,b)$ where $a<b$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

I am facing trouble to solve what are the continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}_l$.

Hint:  Only constant functions are continuous from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}_l$. Indeed, the inverse image of any $[a,b)$ has to be both open and closed, and there are only two such sets in $\mathbb{R}$ , namely, the empty set and $\mathbb{R}$.

But, I have no idea how to solve it? Please help me.

Comment: The "hint" is literally the solution. What part didn't you understand?

Comment: Why the inverse image of $[a,b)$ has to be both open and closed. It is clear that the both open and closed set will be $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ itself, and how this prove that $f$  is constant?

Comment: For $a<b$, $[a,b)$ is open (as given) and  $\bigcup_{x<a}[x,a)\cup \bigcup_{y>b}[b,y)$ is also open.

Comment: Suppose f is continuous but not constant. Then there exist $a,b,x,y$ with $a<b$ and $f(x)=a$ and $f(y)=b.$ Then $f^{-1}[a,b)$ is a non-empty open-and-closed subset of $\Bbb R,$ but is not $\Bbb R$ (because it excludes $y$), which is impossible.

Comment: I think that it's a bit unfair that this question was closed referring to that the previous question had an answer. That wasn't much of an answer, and it wasn't accepted by the OP. I have now added an answer that I hope makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R_\ell$ be continuous. Let $c=f(0).$ You should try to show that $f$ is just the constant map $x\mapsto c.$ To do this you should use the hint. Namely take an interval $[a,b)$ and show that its preimage is either empty or all of $\mathbb R$ depending on whether it contains $c$ or not. Can you do it from here?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to know why should it be constant if $f^{-1} ([a,b)) = \emptyset, \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @user092022 We have $f^{-1}([c,c+\varepsilon)) = \mathbb R$ for every $\varepsilon>0$. So, given $x \in \mathbb R$, $$(\forall \varepsilon>0) \quad c \leq f(x) < c + \varepsilon$$ which implies $f(x) = c$ (otherwise $f(x)>c$, and then we can take $\varepsilon = f(x)-c$ above).